# Sum function not working when trying to add numbers in lists using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a program that takes only even numbers from a range of numbers from 1 to 100 and add all of the even numbers. I am a beginner and I have been trying to get this working since yesterday, and nothing I have tried works. This is my first post, so sorry if the format is wrong but here is my code.

```
for i in range(1, 100):
   if i % 2 == 0:
      x = [I]
      y = sum(x)
      print(y)
```

Comment: What is `I` supposed to be?

Comment: Besides the `I` typo?  In python, `sum` will expect an `iterable` like `list` to be its argument.

Comment: Well, I thought I was storing the range of numbers into "i" to make it a list, and then I was going to use the sum function to add all of the numbers in the list together. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problems with your code has multiple issues that - 1)if you want to get all even numbers from 1 to 100, your range should be (1, 101); 2) the way you build list is wrong (syntax); 3) the **sum** expect an iterable (list).

There are a few ways to accomplish this sum from 1 to 100 (inclusive), here it will start with yours, and try to show **List Comprenshion** and **Generator Expression** way:

```
lst = []   # to store the build-up list
tot = 0    # to store the answer
for i in range(1, 101):
    if i % 2 == 0:        # it's a even number
       lst.append(i)      # store it into lst 

tot = sum(lst)            # 2550
```

Generator expression:

```
all_evens_sum = sum(x for x in range(1, 101) if x % 2 == 0)  # 2550
```

Or List Comprehension:

```
lst = [x for x in range(1, 101) if x % 2 == 0]   # even nums 
total = sum(lst)                # 2550
```